# C# - Работа с классом HttpClient

Tags: c#, uwp

Всем привет! Возник такой вопрос: Как работать с классом `HttCllient` в C#? Как сделать простой `GET` запрос и получить ответ? Пожалуйста, можно примеры работы с этим классом? Желательно пример с асинхроностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;

string header = "ie";
// пытаемся добавить header
if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
}

Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
string httpResponseBody = "";    
try
{
    // отправляем запрос
    httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Подробнее здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient